How to Screen record a particular ViewGroup (Relative Layout), which can contain a video views,surface views, textviews, etc
I am making a view recorder class.
Which can record a video(.mp4) of any view or view group(relative layout), and also record everything that is present inside this view group.
I have looked into MediaProjections API. But it screenRecords everything that is present on the screen including status bar etc. It does not work for me.
I tried using this solution.
https://github.com/z4hyoung/ViewRecorder/tree/master
But As my requirement is that my RelativeLayout contains a VideoView. It records it as black container, because the VideoView extends a surface view and not able to get the content of the surface view.
This what my code looks like,
This is the xml file I want to record the rootView here and all the children inside it. But not any sibling of rootView.
Looking for a generic solution to create a view/viewgroup recorder that can also record contents of the VideoView or any other SurfaceView present inside as children of the ViewGroup.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rootView"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <VideoView
            android:id="@+id/videoView"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp" />
        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/videoView"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/mediaControls"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/seekBar"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnRewind"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Rewind" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnPlayPause"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Play" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnForward"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Forward" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnStartStopRecord"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/start_record" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/hiddenView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This text view should not come in the recorded video"/>
</RelativeLayout>

This is my code for taking bitmap of the view:
 //this works for all except VideoView/SurfaceView
    fun getBitmapFromView(view: View): Bitmap {
        val bitmap =
            Bitmap.createBitmap(view.width, view.height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
        val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
        view.draw(canvas)
        return bitmap
    }

I am calling this method like this:
getBitmapFromView(rootView)

I also tried using this solution. https://github.com/z4hyoung/ViewRecorder/tree/master But As my requirement is that my relative layout contains a video view. It records it as black container, because the video view extends a surface view and not able to get the content of the surface view.

You can consider using below tools to achieve it :


MediaRecorder


Use RenderScript


MediaProjection API


Virtual Display (complex)



MediaProjection API records the whole display. Not possible to record particular ViewGroup with MediaProjection API. This approach uses the virtual display class to get the display.
I am using extended class viewRecorder (this extends MediaRecorder) mentioned above.
Not sure how RenderScript would work for me here.
Please share your working solution here. If you have any:

The built-in screen recording functionalities on Android don't directly support capturing a specific ViewGroup within your app. RenderScript programs might involve more complex operations I would not suggest that .You can consider alternative approach like 1. Render the ViewGroup to a Bitmap or 2. Create a Separate Layout for Recording

I am already doing the rendering of the ViewGroup to a BitMap. But my ViewGroup(Relative Layout) contains a VideoView. It captures it as black container. Any solution where I Can get the bitmap with everything present including the video view. That will resolve my problem.

Updated the post and added the piece of code to get the bitmap from the view. But it doesnt get whats playing inside the VideoView. It captures it as black container.

Now see you have two options : 1. If you only need a static representation of the VideoView (e.g., a thumbnail), you can keep using the current approach with draw(canvas). However, this won't capture the actual video content playing within the VideoView. 2. If your video content is displayed on a SurfaceView instead of a VideoView, you might be able to capture frames directly from the Surface using techniques like screenshots.

Can u share some code?

Akshay have you checked my solution ? You can capture bitmap by doing small tweets in the code the same way as I did for surface view. Hope it helps.

Create a Custom SurfaceView Class:
public class VideoCaptureSurfaceView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;

    public VideoCaptureSurfaceView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        getHolder().addCallback(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        surfaceHolder = holder;
        
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setDisplay(holder);
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(this, R.raw.your_video);
        mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();

        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                // Handle video playback completion (e.g., restart video)
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
        // (Optional) Handle surface changes here if needed
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
            mediaPlayer.release();
            mediaPlayer = null;
        }
        surfaceHolder = null;
    }


    public Bitmap captureFrame() throws IOException {
        if (surfaceHolder == null) {
            throw new IOException("Surface not available");
        }

        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(getWidth(), getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
        canvas.draw(bitmap); 
        surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        return bitmap;
    }
}

MainActivity:
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    private VideoCaptureSurfaceView surfaceView;
  
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);
  
      surfaceView = findViewById(R.id.video_view);
      surfaceView.getHolder().addCallback(this);
    }
  
    implement SurfaceHolder.Callback methods below
}

xml :
<com.your.package.VideoCaptureSurfaceView
  android:id="@+id/video_capture_surface"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" />

Few reference links :

extra padding while taking screenshot using MediaProjection API

https://github.com/suqiang19920518/MediaRecoder1

How to record screen and take screenshots, using Android API?

How to use Mediaprojection library in android to capture screen and convert into mp4 file?

https://developer.android.com/media/grow/media-projection

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/projection/MediaProjection



This is not as per my requirement i want to record the Relative layout and all of its children present in it. children could be video player view, surface view or anything. What You have shared,  is how we implement a video player with a surface view. That is not relevant.

Akshay: some feedback for you. The answer author here appears to have taken a lot of time and care to supply to you something that was intended to be helpful. Your reply appears to be abrupt and rude based on the principle that the answer was not what you wanted. I have downvoted your question as a reminder that politeness is a requirement here.
